# Sometime duplicate record produced despite validation through select statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this old code snippet in PHP. I am saving user vote for each question. For a single uniquest question user can enter only one vote but sometime (not always, unable to reporduce it) the user enter its vote double triple and even six times. Despite selecting and checking that user has already vote or not:
Here is my code:

```
function Save_Vote($pkid, $optionsLen, $tf, $tfVal, $dinnerItemId)
{
    global $con;
    if(isset($_COOKIE['userID']))
    {
        $id =(int) $_COOKIE['userID'];
        $sql = "SELECT *  FROM `vote_poll_output` where `QuesNo` = $pkid and  `EmpPK` = $id ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
        $no_result = mysql_num_rows($result); // total rows

        if(((int)($no_result)) == 0)// Entry not found // new Entry
        {
            $tfArr = explode("_", $tf);
            $tfValArr = explode("_", $tfVal);

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $optionsLen; $i++)
            {
                if($tfArr[$i] =='true')
                {
                    echo 'time val '.$tfValArr[$i];

                    $sql =   "INSERT INTO `vote_poll_output`(`VPOPPK`, `EmpPK`, `QuesNo`, `Option`, `Output`,`vote_Value`, `dinnerItemId`)
                              VALUES (NULL, '$id', '$pkid',  '$i', '".$tfArr[$i]."', '".$tfValArr[$i]."',".$dinnerItemId.")";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Record Exist";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's always an opportunity that a duplicate record is inserted between your `SELECT` and `INSERT`. This would not happen if you had a unique constraint on the table -- add one.

Comment: Where should i add unique constraint? A user can answer multiple unique questions.

Comment: have you tried Trigger and Distinct function from SQL?.A trigger is a stored procedure in database which automatically invokes whenever a special event in the database occurs. For example, a trigger can be invoked when a row is inserted into a specified table or when certain table columns are being updated. The distinct keyword is used in conjunction with select keyword. It is helpful when there is need of avoiding the duplicate values present in any specific columns/table. When we use distinct keyword only the unique values are fetched.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by mustaccio, there is a possibility that a user can place multiple votes by triggering the function several times in parallel (probably by fetching the page more than once on different browser pages and posting all pages at the same time).

You could create a [`UNIQUE` consraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) on the related columns:

> A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row.

Query to add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE vote_poll_output ADD CONSTRAINT unique_poll_per_user UNIQUE(QuesNo, EmpPK);
```

When a user tries a second time, the `INSERT` query will fail on constraint validation. You can trap the error in your application and report it as you wish.

Note: for th constraint to be added to the table, values must conform to it; so you will need to remove the duplicates before you are able to create the constraint (which is a good thing after all...).

---

Another option would be to use MySQL locking mechanism. You can use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to set a read lock when checking if the user already voted, and call `COMMIT` at the end of the function to release the lock. Note that this requires you to disable autocommit, which might not be what you want.